# Change a css class/id at a certain date and time

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change a css element at a certain date and time and to keep it that way.

So, for example, I want

```
<style>

.pink {
color: pink;
}

.orange {
color: orange;
}

</style>

<li><a href="Tab-1" class="pink">Tab 1</a></li>
```

to change to

```
<li><a href="Tab-1" class="orange">Tab 1</a></li>
```

on 10th January 2020

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `class="pink"` and `class="orange"`, not id?

Comment: So you have to check the date, select the element, and set the class.

Comment: You need to provide minimum reproducible example to get a help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should probably do this server side otherwise it will be based on whatever date the clientside clock is set to (or better still, just edit the file on that date if it needs to change)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .pink { color: green; }
    .orange { color: orange; }
</style>
<ul>
    <li><a href="Tab-1" class="pink">Tab 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

The javascript at the end of the html-document:

```
<script>
    // get current date on page load
    var date = new Date();

    // ask for specific date
    if (date.getFullYear() == 2020 && date.getMonth() == 0 && date.getDate() == 10) {

        // get first dom-element with that class 
        var li = document.getElementsByClassName('pink'); 

        // if dom-element exists
        if (li.length > 0) {

            // set classname
            li[0].className = 'orange';
        }           
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: no problem. if possible please accept answer. thank you.